# Adding another light switch to the bathroom

Tags: multiway-switch

We are currently finishing out Master bedroom in the basement. It was left unfinished.  The builders were supposed to add a light above the shower and didn't.

I ran a 14-2 cable from the existing 2 switch box, which controls the toilet light and the fan, to the new box.  I added this box closer to the shower.  This light above the shower has 3 options--main light, night light (orange rgb that glows lightly for some light at night.  This light is also an LED.

I added the new wire to the existing light wiring, black to black, white to white and grounds.  Connected to the switch, however each time I use the switch it trips the breaker.

The new switch is just a plan light switch.

So I've obviously done something wrong... any help would be helpful thanks.

Comment: Three options? You seem to mention only two. Anyway: your new light will have wiring diagrams in the installation manual/pamphlet that explain where all the wires get hooked up. You need to follow those instructions precisely. If you need help, you'll need to include in your question the exact information about make/model of the light. Please update your question.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how light circuits work. You've apparently shorted the existing switch loop, which explains the trips. You can't supply power to a new circuit branch from that location. Please post a diagram or a better description of your wiring, including what comes into the light and fan boxes. I also suggest doing some reading on house wiring fundamentals before you do something _more_ dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

A photo may be helpful here , many times in lighting circuits , the wire colors can be wrong. You might find a hot white wire. If you can post a photo of the location where you tapped into power we may be able to figure it out you have the black hot coming to the new switch then the black from the new light connected to the other side of the switch I hope.